# Linq 2 Sql Compare a local sequence to a query using 'Like' - most efficient method

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I know that there are several similar questions here on SO regarding comparing a list to a query using the Sql 'Like' operation as the comparer.

What I do know is that there is no direct translation using Linq2Sql for this type of comparison. That the provided method Contains() translates to 'IN' in Sql and is a exact comparer. I also know that non-exact comparison methods (SqlMethods.Like(), String.Contains(), StartsWith() and EndsWith()) all work on a single item, and not a list.

Currently, I have my query inside of a foreach loop to provide the required functionality, however, I am concerned about bandwidth on my network as well as the strain on the DB server for large loops.

My question then is this: **what is the most efficient method to perform this operation, while minimizing the network / server load?**

code snippet of my current implementation:

```
using (var context = new GeoDataContext())
{
    var originalSuggestions = new List<SuggestItem>();
    foreach (var suggestItem in suggestionList)
    {
        var item = suggestItem;
        var placeNameList = context.tl_2014_39_places.Where(placeName =>
                       placeName.NAME.Contains(item.Term)).Select(
                           place => place.NAME).ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: If `suggestionList` is not too long you could use a predicate builder to  chain `OR` clauses.

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry for the late response, The suggestionList will vary depending on the choices made by user. I had considered this possibility, but do not know a good way to pull it off on a dynamic list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* need perfomance, you should use raw sql queries in this case. Even then it will not be super-easy (again, if you need perfomance). You have to create custom type like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList AS TABLE (value NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

Then you declare variable of this type (i.e. @terms) as DataTable in C# code, and you do something like

```
select NAME from tl_2014_39_places pl where exists (select 1 from @terms where pl.NAME like '%' + value + '%')
```

or join your table with @terms variable. Then execute SqlCommand and you'll get results in one query. If you will decide to follow the route of raw sql queries, I can help you to find out correct efficient query (query above is just example of how it might look like).

UPDATE: here is full working sample. It assumes there is table tl_2014_39_places with column NAME and that you created custom type StringList using query above:

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var termsTable = new DataTable();
        var suggestionList = new List<string>() {"one", "two", "three"};
        termsTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("value", typeof (string)));
        foreach (var term in suggestionList) {
            termsTable.Rows.Add(term);
        }
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;")) {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select NAME from tl_2014_39_places pl where exists (select 1 from @terms where pl.NAME like '%' + value + '%') ", conn)) {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("terms", SqlDbType.Structured) {
                    Value = termsTable,                        
                    TypeName = "dbo.StringList"
                });
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Note that in general LIKEs with first '%' (i.e. "ends with" queries) are inefficient, since full table needs to be scanned to get the results. But that is unrelated to question itself, and of course it's still MUCH more efficient than looping and multiple db queries. You can also use the following equivalent query instead of where exists:

```
select NAME from tl_2014_39_places pl inner join @terms t on pl.NAME like '%' + t.value + '%'
```

Comment: I am intrigued. I would like to look into this method.

Comment: but, am I right that you want to find all places which names LIKE any item in your suggestionList? Or you need just all places where name is equal to any item in the list?

Comment: First one... all places with names LIKE any items in suggestion list.

Comment: This solution works great. Took a bit to integrate it into my Linq2Sql repository, but...it works! No query loops....just the way I like them... Thanks a ton @Evk

Comment: You are welcome. One more trick, if you are using modern C# 6 (so, Visual Studio 2015) - you can do "nameof(context.tl_2014_39_places)" instead of just hardcoding table name. This way if table name will change in your model your code won't complite and not just fail in runtime.

Comment: Nice, how can I tell if my ASP.net web server can use the new features?

Comment: Well I didn't use asp.net for a long time already. but those are features of C# compiler, not asp.net or something. So if you are able to compile your project using VS2015, you should be fine (except in Razor views, there you might need to update to latest asp.net version).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

If you want to check `Term` has `placeName.NAME`

```
var placeNameList  = context.tl_2014_39_places
                     .Where(placeName => suggestionList
                                         .Select(x => x.Term)
                                         .Contains(placeName.NAME))
                     .Select(place => place.NAME).ToList();
```

If you want to check `placeName.NAME` has `Term`

```
var placeNameList  = context.tl_2014_39_places.AsEnumerable()
                     .Where(placeName => suggestionList.Any(x => placeName.Conaints(x.Term))
                     .Select(place => place.NAME).ToList();
```

To avoid case sensitive searching, you can use `ToLower()` method for both strings of comparison, eg. `placeName.ToLower().Conaints(x.Term.ToLower())`

Comment: Looking at your code, it would seem as if it should work, however, when I ran it, it translated it into a series of individual 'IN' statements, bypassing the 'LIKE' comparison.

Comment: Second example returns this: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: Try `AsEnumerable()` as `context.tl_2014_39_places.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: @xtech This method does work. I do want to note however, that viewing the SQL commands generated, it looks like similar to my snippet given in my original post. I will look into benchmarking this method and compare it to my own. Thanks a ton for the code examples and another approach!